# Rails , when using destroy_all, is there a way to return number of records, if any deleted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

right now I have:

```
PollVote.destroy_all(:user_id => record.user_id, :poll_id => record.poll_id)
```

Is there a way I can get back the number, deleted? 0 or more?

```
deleted_count = PollVote.destroy_all(:user_id => record.user_id, :poll_id => record.poll_id)
```

deleted_count being either 0 or higher?

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Per the documentation, `destroy_all` returns a collection of the objects destroyed. Knowing this, all you need to do is get that collection's `length`:

```
destroyed = PollVote.destroy_all(:user_id => record.user_id, :poll_id => record.poll_id)

destroyed_count = destroyed.length # => The number of records destroyed
```

Comment: A problem I've noticed -- the length doesn't change if some of the records add errors and return false in `before_destroy` callbacks. You'll wind up reporting a `destroyed_count` that's greater than the number of records actually destroyed. (At least for rails versions at the time this answer was posted)

Answer (score 6):

If you use `delete_all`, it will skip all the destroy callbacks for the records that you're deleting (helpful for when you don't want these to run) and it will return the number of records that have been deleted.